# Library not loaded: @rpath/Toast.framework/Toast when debugging flutter app

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos, android-studio

Today when I start debugging the flutter(v2.10.3) app with android studio in macOS 12.5 with M1 chip, shows error like this:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 6F929B73-3F57-461A-BC03-F534D610C50E
CrashReporter Key:   4B9AAD75-30E1-0E03-1197-562F10CD6CAA
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro18,1
Process:             Runner [20899]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/911ED020-A317-4E0E-AA48-A2369DD9EED8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CA725FC8-C3B4-4FC1-91DD-77DE7A74CC3F/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          com.earth.dolphin
Version:             1.0.0 (1.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [17981]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.911ED020-A317-4E0E-AA48-A2369DD9EED8 [4058]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [17866]

Date/Time:           2022-07-30 12:28:46.6656 +0800
Launch Time:         2022-07-30 12:28:46.6099 +0800
OS Version:          macOS 12.5 (21G72)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: DYLD 1 Library missing
Library not loaded: @rpath/Toast.framework/Toast
Referenced from: /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/911ED020-A317-4E0E-AA48-A2369DD9EED8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CA725FC8-C3B4-4FC1-91DD-77DE7A74CC3F/Runner.app/Runner
Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/Toast.framework/Toast' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Toast.framework/Toast' (no such file), '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/911ED020-A317-4E0E-AA48-A2369DD9EED8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CA725FC8-C3B4-4FC1-91DD-77DE7A74CC3F/Runner.app/Frameworks/Toast.framework/Toast' (no such file), '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/911ED020-A317-4E0E-AA48-A2369DD9EED8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/CA725FC8-C3B4-4FC1-91DD-77DE7A74CC3F/Runner.app/Frameworks/Toast.framework/Toast' (no such file), '/Users
(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                                   0x1046efe98 __abort_with_payload + 8
1   dyld                                   0x1046f7024 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 104
2   dyld                                   0x1046f7058 abort_with_payload + 16
3   dyld_sim                               0x1045d411c abort_with_payload + 40
4   dyld_sim                               0x1045a54f4 dyld4::halt(char const*) + 324
5   dyld_sim                               0x1045a19d4 dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 2468
6   dyld_sim                               0x1045a1bf4 _dyld_sim_prepare + 376
7   dyld                                   0x1046aa4c4 dyld4::prepareSim(dyld4::RuntimeState&, char const*) + 1052
8   dyld                                   0x1046a9274 dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 248
9   dyld                                   0x1046a906c start + 488


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000006   x1: 0x0000000000000001   x2: 0x000000016b9747a0   x3: 0x00000000000000ee
    x4: 0x000000016b9743a0   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000020   x9: 0x0000000000000010  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x207972617262694c
   x12: 0x0000000000000027  x13: 0x0000000000000032  x14: 0x000000000013bc60  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000209  x17: 0x00000000000fde70  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x000000016b9743a0  x21: 0x00000000000000ee  x22: 0x000000016b9747a0  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x0000000000000006  x25: 0x000000016b975108  x26: 0x00000001045f00c8  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x000000016b975038   fp: 0x000000016b974360   lr: 0x00000001046f7024
    sp: 0x000000016b974320   pc: 0x00000001046efe98 cpsr: 0x00001000
   far: 0x0000000104624000  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
       0x1046a4000 -        0x104703fff dyld (*) <75627683-a780-32ad-ae34-cf86dd23a26b> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x1045a0000 -        0x1045dbfff dyld_sim (*) <67298116-bb18-3438-b22e-8d2b9d4618e9> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim

Error Formulating Crash Report:
dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed

EOF

-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"Runner","timestamp":"2022-07-30 12:28:46.00 +0800","app_version":"1.0.0","slice_uuid":"791b909c-b70e-34e2-9813-fc2da9cfbed7","build_version":"1.0.0","platform":7,"bundleID":"com.earth.dolphin","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.5 (21G72)","incident_id":"6F929B73-3F57-461A-BC03-F534D610C50E","name":"Runner"}
{
  "uptime" : 6400,
  "procLaunch" : "2022-07-30 12:28:46.6099 +0800",
  "procRole" : "Foreground",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookPro18,1",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 155477543631,
  "coalitionID" : 4058,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.5",
    "build" : "21G72",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2022-07-30 12:28:46.6656 +0800",
  "incident" : "6F929B73-3F57-461A-BC03-F534D610C50E",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 20899,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 155477977313,
  "translated" : false,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "procName" : "Runner",
  "procPath" : "\/Users\/USER\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Devices\/911ED020-A317-4E0E-AA48-A2369DD9EED8\/data\/Containers\/Bundle\/Application\/CA725FC8-C3B4-4FC1-91DD-77DE7A74CC3F\/Runner.app\/Runner",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.0.0","CFBundleVersion":"1.0.0","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.earth.dolphin"},
  "storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"240CB839-BD26-57B4-8B0B-8DD4C99F160A","thirdParty":true},
  "parentProc" : "launchd_sim",
  "parentPid" : 17981,
  "coalitionName" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.911ED020-A317-4E0E-AA48-A2369DD9EED8",
  "crashReporterKey" : "4B9AAD75-30E1-0E03-1197-562F10CD6CAA",
  "responsiblePid" : 17866,
  "responsibleProc" : "SimulatorTrampoline",
  "sleepWakeUUID" : "FEBE014E-816D-4438-913C-962DA1859BCB",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "termination" : {"code":1,"flags":518,"namespace":"DYLD","indicator":"Library missing","details":["(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)"],"reasons":["Library not loaded: @rpath\/Toast.framework\/Toast","Referenced from: \/Users\/USER\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Devices\/911ED020-A317-4E0E-AA48-A2369DD9EED8\/data\/Containers\/Bundle\/Application\/CA725FC8-C3B4-4FC1-91DD-77DE7A74CC3F\/Runner.app\/Runner","Reason: tried: '\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/iOS.simruntime\/Contents\/Resources\/RuntimeRoot\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Toast.framework\/Toast' (no such file), '\/usr\/lib\/swift\/Toast.framework\/Toast' (no such file), '\/Users\/xiaoqiangjiang\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Devices\/911ED020-A317-4E0E-AA48-A2369DD9EED8\/data\/Containers\/Bundle\/Application\/CA725FC8-C3B4-4FC1-91DD-77DE7A74CC3F\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/Toast.framework\/Toast' (no such file), '\/Users\/xiaoqiangjiang\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Devices\/911ED020-A317-4E0E-AA48-A2369DD9EED8\/data\/Containers\/Bundle\/Application\/CA725FC8-C3B4-4FC1-91DD-77DE7A74CC3F\/Runner.app\/Frameworks\/Toast.framework\/Toast' (no such file), '\/Users"]},
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":134213,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":6},{"value":1},{"value":6100043680},{"value":238},{"value":6100042656},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":32},{"value":16},{"value":0},{"value":2340027244252129612},{"value":39},{"value":50},{"value":1293408},{"value":0},{"value":521},{"value":1039984},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":6100042656},{"value":238},{"value":6100043680},{"value":1},{"value":6},{"value":6100046088},{"value":4368302280,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"gProcessInfo"},{"value":0},{"value":6100045880}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":4369379364},"cpsr":{"value":4096},"fp":{"value":6100042592},"sp":{"value":6100042528},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":4369350296,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":4368515072}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":310936,"symbol":"__abort_with_payload","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":340004,"symbol":"abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal","symbolLocation":104,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":340056,"symbol":"abort_with_payload","symbolLocation":16,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":213276,"symbol":"abort_with_payload","symbolLocation":40,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":21748,"symbol":"dyld4::halt(char const*)","symbolLocation":324,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":6612,"symbol":"dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)","symbolLocation":2468,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":7156,"symbol":"_dyld_sim_prepare","symbolLocation":376,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":25796,"symbol":"dyld4::prepareSim(dyld4::RuntimeState&, char const*)","symbolLocation":1052,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":21108,"symbol":"dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)","symbolLocation":248,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":20588,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":488,"imageIndex":0}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 4369039360,
    "size" : 393216,
    "uuid" : "75627683-a780-32ad-ae34-cf86dd23a26b",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4367974400,
    "size" : 245760,
    "uuid" : "67298116-bb18-3438-b22e-8d2b9d4618e9",
    "path" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Library\/Developer\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/iOS.simruntime\/Contents\/Resources\/RuntimeRoot\/usr\/lib\/dyld_sim",
    "name" : "dyld_sim"
  }
],
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=4912K resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=4912K(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=10.0M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=10.0M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nSTACK GUARD                       56.0M        1 \nStack                             8176K        1 \nVM_ALLOCATE                         16K        1 \n__DATA                             112K        5 \n__DATA_CONST                       384K        4 \n__LINKEDIT                        1728K        5 \n__TEXT                            3200K        4 \ndyld private memory               2048K        2 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                             71.3M       23 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {

  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5fb4245a1bbfe8005e33a1e1",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000015
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "61af99aeda72d16a4beb7756",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_DIALOG_ASSETS" : "62b9afba7e9ada388efffaa0"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000271
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
},
  "reportNotes" : [
  "dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed"
]
}

Model: MacBookPro18,1, BootROM 7459.141.1, proc 10:8:2 processors, 32 GB, SMC 
Graphics: Apple M1 Pro, Apple M1 Pro, Built-In
Display: Color LCD, 3456 x 2234 Retina, Main, MirrorOff, Online
Display: dolphin’s MacBook Pro, 3840 x 2160 (2160p/4K UHD 1 - Ultra High Definition), MirrorOff
Memory Module: LPDDR5
AirPort: Wi-Fi, wl0: Apr  6 2022 05:55:54 version 20.90.45.0.8.7.118 FWID 01-e7138ff2
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB31Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc.
```

The flutter app start on iPhone XR emulator and suddenly exists. I did not change the project code recently, why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this problem? The android studio version is:

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.5
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2280M
Cores: 10
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart (212.5744), org.moe.community (1.4.10), com.thoughtworks.gauge (212.4746.52), org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.7.10-release-333-AS5457.46), io.flutter (69.0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found upgrade the `ruby-macho` version greater than 2.5.1 could fix this problem:

```
➜  ios git:(main) ✗ sudo gem install ruby-macho
Password:
Fetching ruby-macho-3.0.0.gem
Successfully installed ruby-macho-3.0.0
Parsing documentation for ruby-macho-3.0.0
Installing ri documentation for ruby-macho-3.0.0
Done installing documentation for ruby-macho after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

more information could fetch from here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92896